# Database abstraction class in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, sql

Here is the link to the revised version of this code:
[Database abstraction class in C# (version 2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174980/database-abstraction-class-in-c-version-2)

I am new to C# and have coded a database abstraction class that I would like to get comments on.  It uses prepared SQL statements.  I would like this to not get distracted with prepared statements versus non-prepared statements discussion; please just review the code assuming prepared statements are appropriate for this class.

```
class DatabaseAccess
{
    private SqlCommand alreadyDownloadedCommand;
    private SqlCommand markedDownloadedCommand;

    public DatabaseAccess()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
                                   "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=database; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

        myConnection.Open();
        alreadyDownloadedCommand = getAlreadyDownloadedCommand(myConnection);
        markedDownloadedCommand = getMarkedDownloadedCommand(myConnection);
    }

    private SqlCommand getMarkedDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string markDownloadedInsert =
        @"insert into dbo.InspectionsDownloaded(FileName)
          values (@FileName)
        ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
        command.CommandText = markDownloadedInsert;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, 80));

        return command;
    }
    private SqlCommand getAlreadyDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string alreadyDownloadedQuery =
        @"select count(*) as numDownloaded
            from dbo.InspectionsDownloaded id
           where id.FileName = @FileName
        ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
        command.CommandText = alreadyDownloadedQuery;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, 80));

        return command;
    }
    public Boolean AlreadyDownloaded(String filename)
    {
        Int32 rowCount;
        alreadyDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        rowCount = (Int32)alreadyDownloadedCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        return (rowCount != 0);
    }
    public void MarkDownloaded(String filename)
    {
        markedDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        markedDownloadedCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am new to C# and have coded a database abstraction class that I
>   would like to get comments on.  It uses prepared SQL statements.

No, it doesn't. If you want it to use prepared statements then you have to call `Prepare()` on the `SqlCommand` instances.

Whether you really want actual prepared statements or whether you just want to leave escaping to the library is, as you say, up to you.

---

> ```
> class DatabaseAccess
> {
>     private SqlCommand alreadyDownloadedCommand;
>     private SqlCommand markedDownloadedCommand;
> ```

Both `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` are `IDisposable`. Best practices would require you to make `DatabaseAccess` implement `IDisposable` by disposing of all three.

---

> ```
>         SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
>                                    "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
>                                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
>                                    "database=database; " +
>                                    "connection timeout=30");
> ```

If this is for a throwaway project, hard-coding the connection string like that is acceptable. If it's for a "serious" project then you should really get the connection string from `App.config` with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`. That has the benefit of allowing you to have dev and prod configurations, as well as to handle server migrations, password cycling, etc. without recompiling.

---

> ```
>         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
>         command.CommandText = markDownloadedInsert;
> ```

Why not this?

```
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(markDownloadedInsert, connection);
```

---

> ```
>         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, 80));
> ```

...

> ```
>     public void MarkDownloaded(String filename)
>     {
>         markedDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
> ```

If `filename` is longer than 80 characters, it will be silently truncated. I would think it advisable to check the length and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if it's too long. Similarly in the other method.

---

> ```
>     public Boolean AlreadyDownloaded(String filename)
>     {
>         Int32 rowCount;
> ```

Finally, some debatable points of style. I think it's quite unusual to use `Boolean`, `String`, `Int32` instead of the aliases `bool`, `string`, `int`. And it's fairly conventional that a method (or property) which tests a condition and returns a `bool` should have a name beginning `Is`: here `IsAlreadyDownloaded`.

Comment: All excellent feedback.  I acted on all of it.

Answer (score 3):

Just few comments additional to Peter Taylors answer:

- Method names should start with an upper-case letter in C#
- It is not always a good idea to open the connection in constructor and keep them open, but it depends on the use case. Alternatively, you could provide methods `Open` and `Close` and allow the outer context to control the connection's state. If required, the connection should be opened automatically (and closed afterwards) before executing commands.
- The private instance variables (commands) should be read-only
- Since the variables `alreadyDownloadedQuery` and `markDownloadedInsert` are within the scope of the method, it makes no sense (IMHO) to use such descriptive names. I would just call it `sql` which makes the code more readable.

Below is an example implementation with the suggestions above (and from Peter):

```
public class DatabaseAccess : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection myConnection;
    private readonly SqlCommand myMarkedDownloadedCommand;
    private readonly SqlCommand myAlreadyDownloadedCommand;

    public DatabaseAccess(string connectionString)
    {
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myMarkedDownloadedCommand = CreateMarkedDownloadedCommand(myConnection);
        myAlreadyDownloadedCommand = CreateMarkedDownloadedCommand(myConnection);
    }

    public void Open() => myConnection.Open();
    public void Close() => myConnection.Close();
    public bool IsOpen => myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open;

    private static SqlCommand CreateMarkedDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string sql =
        @"insert into dbo.InspectionsDownloaded(FileName)
                      values (@FileName)";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, 80));
        command.Prepare();
        return command;
    }
    private static SqlCommand CreateAlreadyDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string sql =
        @"select count(*) as numDownloaded
                        from dbo.InspectionsDownloaded id
                       where id.FileName = @FileName";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text, 80));
        command.Prepare();
        return command;
    }
    public Boolean AlreadyDownloaded(String filename)
    {
        myAlreadyDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        return RunCommand(myAlreadyDownloadedCommand, c => (Int32)c.ExecuteScalar() != 0);
    }

    public void MarkDownloaded(String filename)
    {
        myMarkedDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        RunCommand(myMarkedDownloadedCommand, c => c.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }

    private TValue RunCommand<TValue>(SqlCommand cmd, Func<SqlCommand, TValue> commandAction)
    {
        var isOpen = IsOpen;
        try
        {
            if (!isOpen) Open();
            return commandAction(cmd);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isOpen) Close();
        }
    }

    // Impl. IDisposable and dispose connection and command objects.
}
```

Comment: You don't need the fields to store copies of the `SqlCommand`s if the public methods create their own temporary copies.

Comment: Right, thanks... Actually I am a fan of recreating commands each time instead of reusing the instances. But I am not sure if that works with command preparation. Do you know if command preparation works also with different command instances?

Comment: I would assume not, but I don't actually know. It's possible that the `SqlConnection` would keep a cache for looking up prepared statement ID by command text, but that would seem to break separation of responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to spend the time abstracting things then you probably want to invest some effort in refactoring a lot of your common logic into helper functions. Starting with the very first issue, a hard-coded connection string, we can create a function that'll build one out of components:

```
public static string BuildConnectionString(string serverName, string databaseName, int connectTimeout = 30, string userId = null, string password = null) {
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = serverName;
    builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
    builder.ConnectTimeout = connectTimeout;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) {
        builder.UserID = userId;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) {
        builder.Password = userId;
    }

    if ((builder.UserID == null) && (builder.Password == null)) {
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    }

    return new DatabaseAccess(builder.ConnectionString);
}
```

By changing the class around a little bit we can use this string to construct a new connection:

```
public class DatabaseAccess : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection m_dbConnection;
    private bool m_disposed;

    public DatabaseAccess(SqlConnection connection) {
        m_dbConnection = connection;
    }
    public DatabaseAccess(string connectionString) : this(new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!m_disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                m_dbConnection.Dispose();
            }

            m_disposed = true;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can add some helper methods to simplify the creation of commands, execution of SQL, and retrieval of single values:

```
public static SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60) {
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = commandText;
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

    return command;
}
public static int Execute(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
    using (var command = CreateCommand(connection, commandText, commandType, commandTimeout)) {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        Open(connection);

        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
public static object GetValue(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
    using (var command = CreateCommand(connection, commandText, commandType, commandTimeout)) {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        Open(connection);

        return command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}

private static void Open(SqlConnection connection) {
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Combining all of this with your original code results in something like the below; there are still some opportunities to improve things even further (for example, code duplication exists in the `Execute` and `GetValue` methods that might be worth refactoring into a separate method (especially if one were to add more robust logic).

```
public class DatabaseAccess : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection m_dbConnection;
    private bool m_disposed;

    public DatabaseAccess(SqlConnection connection) {
        m_dbConnection = connection;
    }
    public DatabaseAccess(string connectionString) : this(new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!m_disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                m_dbConnection.Dispose();
            }

            m_disposed = true;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    public bool AlreadyDownloaded(string filename) {
        var fileNameParam = new SqlParameter("@FileName", SqlDbType.Text, 80) {
            Value = filename
        };
        var rowCount = GetValue(
            connection: m_dbConnection,
            commandText: "select count(*) as numDownloaded from dbo.InspectionsDownloaded id where id.FileName = @FileName",
            parameters: new[] {
                fileNameParam
            }
        );

        return (((int)rowCount) != 0);
    }
    public void MarkDownloaded(string filename) {
        var fileNameParam = new SqlParameter("@FileName", SqlDbType.Text, 80) {
            Value = filename
        };

        Execute(
            connection: m_dbConnection,
            commandText: "insert into dbo.InspectionsDownloaded(FileName) values(@FileName)",
            parameters: new[] {
                fileNameParam
            }
        );
    }

    public static DatabaseAccess Create(string serverName, string databaseName, int connectTimeout = 30, string userId = null, string password = null) {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = serverName;
        builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
        builder.ConnectTimeout = connectTimeout;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) {
            builder.UserID = userId;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) {
            builder.Password = userId;
        }

        return new DatabaseAccess(builder.ConnectionString);
    }
    public static SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60) {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = commandType;
        command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

        return command;
    }
    public static int Execute(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
        using (var command = CreateCommand(connection, commandText, commandType, commandTimeout)) {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            Open(connection);

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    public static object GetValue(SqlConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int commandTimeout = 60, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
        using (var command = CreateCommand(connection, commandText, commandType, commandTimeout)) {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            Open(connection);

            return command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    private static void Open(SqlConnection connection) {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t Fixed.

Comment: It's much better now ;-)