# Database abstraction class in C# (version 2)

Tags: c#, sql

Below is my revised version of this code after I acted on the suggestions:

[Database abstraction class in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174829/database-abstraction-class-in-c)

```
class DatabaseAccess : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private SqlCommand alreadyDownloadedCommand;
    private SqlCommand markedDownloadedCommand;
    // *FieldSize variables match the size of the field in the database.
    private const int FileNameFieldSize = 80;
    private const int AppTypeFieldSize = 2;
    private const int UserNameFieldSize = 8;

    public DatabaseAccess(string dbconnectionstring)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);

        connection.Open();
        alreadyDownloadedCommand = getAlreadyDownloadedCommand(connection);
        markedDownloadedCommand = getMarkedDownloadedCommand(connection);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        alreadyDownloadedCommand.Dispose();
        markedDownloadedCommand.Dispose();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    private void ValidateFieldSize(string fielddata, int fieldsize)
    {
        if (fielddata.Length > fieldsize)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Parameter size too large");
        }
    }
    private SqlCommand getMarkedDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string sql =
        @"insert into dbo.InspectionsDownloaded(FileName)
          values (@FileName)
        ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, FileNameFieldSize));
        command.Prepare();
        return command;
    }

    private SqlCommand getAlreadyDownloadedCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        const string sql =
        @"select count(*) as numDownloaded
            from dbo.InspectionsDownloaded id
           where id.FileName = @FileName
        ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, FileNameFieldSize));
        command.Prepare();
        return command;
    }
    public bool IsAlreadyDownloaded(string filename)
    {
        int rowCount;
        ValidateFieldSize(filename, FileNameFieldSize);
        alreadyDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        rowCount = (Int32)alreadyDownloadedCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        return (rowCount != 0);
    }
    public int MarkDownloaded(string filename)
    {
        ValidateFieldSize(filename, FileNameFieldSize);
        markedDownloadedCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filename;
        return(markedDownloadedCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some organization nitpicks first :

- Your class file should start with the `const`
- Even your private functions should be PascalCased meaning `getAlreadyDownloadedCommand` should be `GetAlreadyDownloadedCommand`
- Your public methods should appear before your private methods IMO

You don't implement the `Dispose` pattern correctly. You should check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) but basically, to properly dispose your object, the pattern is the following :

```
public void Dispose()
{  
    Dispose(true);  
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
}  

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{  
    if (disposing){  
        if (connection != null) connection.Dispose();  
        //etc.
    }  
}
```

I must say I'm not 100% *why* we need to do it this way, but this is how it is supposed to be implemented according to Microsoft's documentation and developer tools like Resharper.

When you have a public method/constructor/etc, you should always check your input for `null`. Don't trust the user of your code, even if it's yourself! If you check your inputs for `null`, you'll know very fast if your input is `null`, instead of having a weird exception that tells you little to nothing.

```
public DatabaseAccess(string dbconnectionstring)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(dbconnectionstring) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbconnectionstring));

    connection = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);

    connection.Open();
    alreadyDownloadedCommand = getAlreadyDownloadedCommand(connection);
    markedDownloadedCommand = getMarkedDownloadedCommand(connection);
}
```

Comment: It is worth to say that Visual Studio has built-in command to implement `IDisposable` with Dispose pattern. Also in this case you'll get some useful comments saying you don't need `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` if you don't override finalizer.

Comment: The `Dispose(bool disposing)` construction makes it easier to correctly implement finalizers and disposal in class hierarchies. The OP's disposal code isn't incorrect, it's just less future/extension-proof.